# JS : Display multiple messages during await

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

I have a sequence of 3 await that call a function:

```
const call1 = await doit('register/call1','otp=' + otp, 'post')
             .then(() => {
                    move();
             });

const call2 = await doit('register/call2','otp=' + otp, 'post')
             .then(() => {
                    move();
             });

const call3 = await doit('register/call3','otp=' + otp, 'post')
             .then(() => {
                    move();
             });
```

doit() function is an ajax call.

The move() function display a progress bar:

```
//Progress Bar
    var width = 0;
    function move() {
        width += 100/3;
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        if (width <= 101) {
            elem.style.width = width + "%";
        }
    }
```

Under this progress bar, i would like to display several messages like:
"Be patient, the work is in progress..."
"Wait again a minute..."
"Please wait, it's almost finish"
... and a lot more

Actually, i would like the messages to appear during the await calls.

I tried to add this after the await:

```
$('#progress_bar_message').html('Creation 1/3...');
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#progress_bar_message').html("Creation 1/3... Be patient, the work is in progress...");
            }, 4000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#progress_bar_message').html("Creation 1/3... Wait again a minute...");
            }, 8000);
```

But it doesn't work well.
Maybe in the ajax call (jquery) ? in the Beforesend ?

Comment: Make your `move` method accept a string argument containing a message. Set the message after setting the progress.

Comment: Or (and/or) add a parameter to `doit` with the relevant message

Comment: Yes but for first call i would like 2 messages, the second call, 8 messages and last call just 1 message.

Comment: If you want to have full control over messages and the time of showing them, you should consider using a socket-based approach.

Comment: *first call I would like 2 messages, the second call 8* - pass in an array of messages - or use params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Progress's complete percents need to be controlled in move function .**

In setTimeout callback ,we don't know the exact timing while one of Ajax has finished.

**2. Create a tip flag to control whether progress_bar_message appear or not. When progress_bar_message need be changed in setTimeout callback, check the flag. Set a complete tip when all Ajaxes resolved.**

```js
var width = 0;
var process = 0;
function move() {
  width += 100 / 3;
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  if (width <= 101) {
    process += 1;
    $("#progress_bar_message").html(`Creation ${process}/3...`);
    elem.style.width = width + "%";
  }
}
const doit = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, 5000);
  });
let showTips = true;
const requestCall = async () => {
  const call1 = await doit("register/call1", "post").then(() => {
    move();
  });

  const call2 = await doit("register/call2", "post").then(() => {
    move();
  });

  const call3 = await doit("register/call3", "post").then(() => {
    move();
  });
  showTips = false;
  $("#progress_bar_tips").html("All complete");
};

requestCall();
const handleShowTips = () => {
  const tipsMap = [
    "Be patient, the work is in progress...",
    "Wait again a minute..."
  ];
  let tipsCount = 0;
  const showTipsAfter3Second = () => {
    if (showTips) {
      $("#progress_bar_tips").html(tipsMap[tipsCount % tipsMap.length]);
      tipsCount += 1;
      setTimeout(() => {
        showTipsAfter3Second();
      }, 3000);
    }
  };
  showTipsAfter3Second();
};
handleShowTips();
```

```css
.bar-container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
#myBar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<span id="progress_bar_message"></span>
<span id="progress_bar_tips"></span>
<div class="bar-container">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Comment: A link can be useful, but in this case it would be good to embed the solution inside your question. Did you know that you can include a runnable snippet? Check out toolbar in editor...